# Why can't Safari connect to localhost?

Tags: safari, localhost, hosts, symlink-traversal

I have a proper /etc/hosts file with the following contents:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

When I try to access a server I have running on my local computer, whether it is Apache on port 80, or another server running on another port, I can't access it in Safari.  Yet I can access them just fine in Chrome.  Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that I forgot I had made a symlink for /etc/hosts to a file I store elsewhere so I always have access to it if my system crashes, etc.  Apparently, Safari doesn't follow the symlink for /etc/hosts.  I made a hard link so I have a copy elsewhere, and now Safari recognizes localhost servers.

Comment: Hello, can you please explain the process ? i've the same problem